# pythontex successfully installed, but nothing appearing with print statement

Tags: pdftex, python, pythontex

I believe that I have successfully installed pythontex; it appears as installed in the MiKTeX console, and when I enter `pythontex --version` in the console I see `PythonTeX 0.17`.

I am using TeXStudio and under the Configure menu I have PdFLaTeX set to: `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex  pythontex %.tex pdflatex %.tex`.

When I compile from within TeXStudio, the messages box shows (in green) `Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex  pythontex "main".tex pdflatex "main".tex`, and under the log, I see `No file pythontex-files-main/main.pytxmcr.`. This process creates a file, `main.pytxcode`.

When I run the following batch script, a folder `pythontex-files-main` appears. However the code still does not appear.

```
pdflatex main.tex
pythontex main.tex
pdflatex main.tex
```

I have Python 2.7 installed and use it on a regular basis. Any insight as to why this is not working for me?

**EDIT:**

- Some things that worked: adding python, and pythontex to path.
- Explicitly typing the path and running in command prompt as shown below:
- `python 'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex.py' main.tex`
- I actually had an error in python code - it should not be indented.
- The batch script now works, but python code will not run from TeXStudio still. (even if I replace the PdfLaTeX settings verbatim with what is in the batch script)

MWE below:

```latex
\documentclass{article} %
\usepackage{pythontex}
% C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex.py (pythontex2 and 3 also here)
\begin{document}
Code should execute be below:
%
%
%\printpythontex  % tried random thing
%\stdoutpythontex  % tried random thing
\begin{pycode}
print(r'\begin{center}')
print(r'\textit{A message from Python!}')
print(r'\end{center}')
\end{pycode}

%
%\printpythontex  % tried random thing
%\stdoutpythontex  % tried random thing
\end{document}
```

Comment: For me it is working, I also have MikTeX and use pythontex frequently. Althugh I have python 3.x ; Are you sure, that python is in your PATH and such .. ?

Comment: Thanks for trying. I open up a cmd prompt in an arbitrary folder, type `python` and see `Python 2.7.9 ...`, so that would indicate that is in my path correct?

Comment: I am at windows. Type "where python" in command prompt, that should check you have python set-up ok ...

Comment: I should have specidied I am on Windows 10. I type `where python` but no result. When looking at "Environment Variables" I do see C:\Python27

Comment: OK, I am using win10 too. That means that you dont have python in your PATH environment variable. Look around in stack exchange or net to find out how to set your PATH, or reinstall python and in installer choose to add python to your PATH variable.
Sometimes its not recommended, but I think that only expert users would have more than 1 version of python on their PC.

Comment: Ah, perhaps there is an issue: I have 2.7 and 3.7 installed. I have two versions because we use software that requires 2, but I use some packages that are post-3. I will definitely try this on my home computer as well. 
Prior to your comments, I had followed the steps shown here: https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path, no success.

Comment: Two versions of python is I think definitely the cause even more that none is recognized by your OS (I dont know how that happens) ... I am pretty much new (but enthusiastic) in python, but I think I have read somewhere on stack exchange that it can be set up, but you need to make some extra steps to make it work.

Comment: Curious, why do you not think it is recognized by my OS? I can view the version by typing `python` in an arbitrary folder.

Comment: Well, I thought so after you wrote that writing 'where python' in command line doesnt produce information about location of your python instalation. I am pretty sure that that means that your python cant be found by other applications ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100771/discussion-between-likethevegetable-and-tomas-krulis).

Comment: Ah, just checked again and it does show now. Alas, code is still not showing.

Comment: @likethevegetable did you come to a solution on this?

Comment: @Colin I did get it working. I have to manually compile the code from powershell with `pythontex main`. Unfortunately the TeXstudio command does not work. I'm sure it's an easy fix.